# CMake errors while building MTConnect C++ Agent on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake

So I'm attempting to build the MTConnect agent on my Windows 10 PC. I installed GitBash and cloned the repository from GitHub using

> $ git clone https://github.com/mtconnect/cppagent.git

command on GitBash. I then navigated to the `cppagent` directory on GitBash and installed the required submodules using

> git submodule init

and then

> git submodule update

I then opened Windows Command Prompt, navigated to the `cppagent` folder, and ran

> cmake .

This built a Visual Studio 2015 solution in the `cppagent` folder. So I opened the `.sln` file with VS 2015 and attempted to build the solution. However, I got the following errors:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  Checking Build System
>   1>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Cannot restore timestamp C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp**
>   1>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   1>  See also "C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   1>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Unable to open check cache file for write. C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache**
>   1>  CMake Configure step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.  Attempting to stop IDE build.
>   2>------ Build started: Project: UPDATE_VERSION, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   3>------ Build started: Project: cppunit, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   4>------ Build started: Project: libxml2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   2>  Building Custom Rule C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/agent/CMakeLists.txt
>   2>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Cannot restore timestamp C:\Program Files\Git\cppagent\agent\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp**
>   2>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   2>  See also "C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   2>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Unable to open check cache file for write. C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache**
>   3>  Building Custom Rule C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/cppunit_make/CMakeLists.txt
>   4>  Building Custom Rule C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/libxml2_make/CMakeLists.txt
>   4>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Cannot restore timestamp C:\Program Files\Git\cppagent\libxml2\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp**
>   3>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Cannot restore timestamp C:\Program Files\Git\cppagent\cppunit\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp**
>   3>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   3>  See also "C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   4>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   4>  See also "C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   4>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Unable to open check cache file for write. C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache**
>   5>------ Build started: Project: agent, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   3>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Unable to open check cache file for write. C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache**
>   6>------ Build started: Project: agent_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   5>  Building Custom Rule C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/agent/CMakeLists.txt
>   5>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Cannot restore timestamp C:\Program Files\Git\cppagent\agent\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp**
>   5>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   5>  See also "C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   5>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Unable to open check cache file for write. C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache**
>   6>  Building Custom Rule C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/test/CMakeLists.txt
>   6>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Cannot restore timestamp C:\Program Files\Git\cppagent\test\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp**
>   6>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   6>  See also "C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   6>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Unable to open check cache file for write. C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache**
>   7>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   8>------ Skipped Build: Project: cov, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   8>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
>  
>   7>  Building Custom Rule C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeLists.txt
>   7>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Cannot restore timestamp C:\Program Files\Git\cppagent\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp**
>   7>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   7>  See also "C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   7>**CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Unable to open check cache file for write. C:/Program Files/Git/cppagent/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache**
>   9>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   9>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
>  
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 7 failed, 0 up-to-date, 2 skipped =========

As you can see, the same two errors are repeated for almost every project in the solution. I am completely new to CMake and have no idea what the problem is. I Googled each error specifically and could not find any definitive answer.

I am using CMake 3.6 RC. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you just have no permissions to write into `C:/Progrm Files` from Visual Studio.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Holy cow you're right.. I've been banging my head against the wall for 3 days now over this.. Don't I feel like a noob